# Easisest way to convert whole DVD folder (all titles and chapters) to MKV file(s)?

Tags: conversion, mkv

I have lots of movies stored as DVD folders(.bup, .vob, .ifo files); I am looking for the easiest way to convert each folder into one (or more) mkv files (preferably by using freeware program(s))

HandBrake does a decent job; there is only one problem - it would not convert all **titles** automatically, you'd have to go and do it one title after another one; would anyone suggest a good DVD->MKV converter, or, perhaps, describe how to force HandBrake to convert all titles (just as is takes all chapters for each title)?

Answer (score 3):

If you wrote a small script (say in python) you could use the Command line client of the software convert all the videos sequentially. Python has good system calls functionality and make this quite easy.